# Distance on riemann sphere

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, metric-spaces, riemann-surfaces

Let we have $C$ the set of complex numbers and $z_1 , z_2 \in C $ we have $Z_1 , Z_2 \in S$ correspond on riemann sphere and we will define : $$ d(Z_1,Z_2)=\frac{2|z_1-z_2|}{\sqrt{1+|z_1|^2} \sqrt{1+|z_2|^2} } $$
How can I prove $d$ is a distance

Comment: Are $z_1, z_2$ images of $Z_1, Z_2$ under the stereographi projection?

Comment: @gary yes man 

Comment: Then , in general, if d(x,y) is a metric in X and h: X-->Y is a homeomorphism, then d(h(x),h(y)) is a metric in Y, i.e., metrics pullback by homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Calculate the Euclidean distance between $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ then express it in terms of $z_1$ and $z_2$.